# Python3 decorating conditionally?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, decorator

Is it possible to decorate a function based on a condition?

a'la:

```
if she.weight() == duck.weight(): 
    @burn
def witch():
    pass
```

I'm just wondering if logic could be used (when `witch` is called?) to figure out whether or not to decorate `witch` with `@burn`?

If not, is it possible to create a condition within the decorator to the same effect? (`witch` being called undecorated.)

Answer (score 14):

You can create a 'conditionally' decorator:

```
>>> def conditionally(dec, cond):
    def resdec(f):
        if not cond:
            return f
        return dec(f)
    return resdec
```

Usage example follows:

```
>>> def burn(f):
    def blah(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'hah'
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return blah

>>> @conditionally(burn, True)
def witch(): pass
>>> witch()
hah

>>> @conditionally(burn, False)
def witch(): pass
>>> witch()
```

Comment: +1 I like this more than my solution, as it keeps with the decorator theme, and looks pretty clean, imo.

Comment: This is an old answer, but does anyone know how to pass arguments to the conditionally-wrapped decorator using this pattern?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to [enable/disable decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Enable.2FDisable_Decorators) by reassignment.

> ```
> def unchanged(func):
>     "This decorator doesn't add any behavior"
>     return func
>
> def disabled(func):
>     "This decorator disables the provided function, and does nothing"
>     def empty_func(*args,**kargs):
>         pass
>     return empty_func
>
> # define this as equivalent to unchanged, for nice symmetry with disabled
> enabled = unchanged
>
> #
> # Sample use
> #
>
> GLOBAL_ENABLE_FLAG = True
>
> state = enabled if GLOBAL_ENABLE_FLAG else disabled
> @state
> def special_function_foo():
>     print "function was enabled"
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Decorators are just syntactical sugar for re-defining the function, ex:

```
def wrapper(f):
    def inner(f, *args):
        return f(*args)
    return lambda *args: inner(f, *args)

def foo():
    return 4
foo = wrapper(foo)
```

Which means that you could do it the old way, before the syntactical sugar existed:

```
def foo():
    return 4
if [some_condition]:
    foo = wrapper(foo)
```