# Django - setting that will disable or enable @login_required decorator in all my views

Tags: django

In my django project views.py file, I use @login_required decorator to prevent access to certain views for anonymous users.

I want to add possibility to easily disable this, by using simple switch in settings.py, like:

ALLOW_ANONYMOUS =1

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, but it means modifying decorators.py which may cause problems later on. But it should work:

In settings.py add

```
ALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True
```

Then in decorators.py, in your django directory, the function that is called in login_required is user_passes_test, you can add an "or" condition where it evaluates login. Like this:

```
if test_func(request.user) or settings.ALLOW_ANONYMOUS:
```

So if ALLOW_ANONYMOUS is True, it will behave as if user is logged in. If False, normal behavior applies.

Note that it may have other unwanted effects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [conditional decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773555/python3-decorating-conditionally) will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do that. If you don't want much hassle you can cheat at the source of @login_required decorator and provide a test like that:

```
from django.conf import settings

 def allow_annonymous(user):
     return settings.ALLOW_ANONYMOUS
```

and pass it in the every decorator:

```
@login_required(function=allow_annonymous, login_url='/accounts/login/')
```

mind that this is undocumented and subject to change