# How to toggle the action of a decorator in Python3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, decorator

I have a decorator `@newthread` which wraps functions to run in a separate thread (using `wraps` from `functools` and `Thread` from `threading`). However, there are some functions for which I only want this to happen some of the time.

At the moment, I have `@newthread` check the keyword arguments of the function to be wrapped and if it finds a bool `new_thread` equal to `True` then it runs the function in a separate thread, otherwise it runs the function normally. For example,

```
@newthread
def foo(new_thread=False)
     # Do stuff...

foo() # Runs normally
foo(new_thread=True) # Runs in new thread
```

Is this the canonical way of doing this, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kevin What code is there to be reviewed? The `@newthread` implementation isn't shown, and the `foo` stuff is all hypothetical.

Comment: Or you could do `thread_foo = newthread(foo)` and use `foo` or `thread_foo` depending on your needs, but I think your way is better.

Comment: @200_success: Yeah, it would probably help if OP actually provided some code to review.

Comment: @Kevin It's just not asking for a code review at all.

Comment: @200_success: "Is this the canonical way of doing this, or am I missing something?" sounds like a code review request to me.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare This would likely be closed on Code Review as stub code, due to the omitted code here. If the OP provides the full code, and isn't asking for new features, then it's on-topic.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare 1. Speaking as a moderator of Code Review, I guarantee you that this question would be immediately closed on Code Review, for the reasons stated above.  2. "Because it belongs on Code Review" is not a valid reason to classify this question as off-topic for Stack Overflow. See the [help/on-topic] for a list of valid off-topic reasons.  Also read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Comment: What about conditional decorater ?
See [Python3 decorating conditionally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773555/python3-decorating-conditionally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `newthread` as a decorator, then.  A decorator is just a function that takes a function and returns a function.

If you want it to run in the current thread, call

```
foo(some, params)
```

If you want to run `foo` in a new thread, call

```
newthread(foo)(some, params)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@newthread
def foo(new_thread=False)
     # Do stuff...

foo() # Runs normally
foo(new_thread=True) # Runs in new thread
```

That is good - but, I for one, would prefer to have the decorator do consume the "new_thread" argument, instead of having it showing on the parameter list of the decorated functions.

Also, you could use a "default" value so that you'd pick the actual need to use a different thread from somewhere else (like an enviroment variable):

```
MARKER = object()
def newthread(func):
    def wrapper(*args, newthread=MARKER, **kwargs):
        if newthread is MARKER:
              newthread = os.environ.get("force_threads", True)
        if newthread:
             ...
             # cretae new thread and return future-like object
        else:
             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```